# How to solve this differential equation (numerically)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a nasty differential equation that I need to solve numerically. And I don't know where to start...

A simplified version of the equation:
$$x = \int_0^L \dfrac{\partial f(x,s)}{\partial x}~ds $$

***What's the equation about:*** $x$ is a curvature of an elastic rod. This equation calculates $x$ when a force is applied to the rod. I have the value for $x$ in its rest position.

$f(x,s)$ is a sum of parts that all have dependencies of $x$ (and not in a nice way...)

Not sure if this is enough information to work with. If it's not, let me know.

Comment: Depends what program you are using. I'm sure there would be a matlab function you could call to solve integral equations. Or, alternatively, turn the above into a differential equation (as long as some conditions hold) and code that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find a $f(x,y)$ which solves
$$
x = \int\limits_{0}^L f_x(x,s) \, ds 
$$
If $f$ is continous this is roughly 
$$
f_x(x, \sigma) = (1/L) x
$$
for some $\sigma \in (0,L)$,
so it looks not very constraining and has probably many possible solutions.

Trying a quadratic polynomial:

For
$$
f(x,y) = a + bx + cy + d x^2 + e y^2 + g x y \Rightarrow \\
f_x(x,y) = b + 2d x + g y
$$
this turns into
$$
x = (b + 2dx)L + (1/2) g L^2
$$
and implies 
$$
f(x,y) = a + cy +(1/(2L))x^2+ey^2
$$